# Java org.apache.http.ssl.SSLContext not found

Tags: java, httpclient

I am trying to build a HttpClient but can't just figure out how to resolve this ClassNotFound-Error. I installed "org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.1.3" with maven and several other libraries but yet i won't work.

Code:

```
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.config.CookieSpecs;
import org.apache.http.client.config.RequestConfig;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.client.utils.URIBuilder;
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.util.*;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String bearerToken = "BLABLA";
        HttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom().setDefaultRequestConfig(RequestConfig.custom().setCookieSpec(CookieSpecs.STANDARD).build()).build();
    }
}
```

The corresponding error message:

```
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=on -Dswing.aatext=true
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/ssl/SSLContexts
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder.build(HttpClientBuilder.java:977)
    at Twitter.main(Twitter.java:23)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.http.ssl.SSLContexts
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
```

The maven repos i have installed currently:

```
oauth.signpost:signpost-commonshttp4:2.0.0
org.json:json:20200518
org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.1.3
```

Please note, that i am new to Java and Intellij-IDE.

I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try using "httpcore - 4.1.3" (of the same version as of your `httpclient` jar)  jar file. You would be able to import `org.apache.http.ssl.SSLContexts` successfully.

Answer (score -1):

Is it possible for you to use

> org.apache.httpcomponents
> httpclient     4.5.2

and then `import org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLContexts`

Comment: Thanks for your response. Unfortunately it throws the exact same error.

Comment: where are you specifying libs? in maven? or local.jar file?

Comment: I am specifying them in maven.

Comment: if possible can you attache that in your question?

Comment: I am not quite sure what you mean exactly. Let me just summarize how i did things so far. To add a library i opened the project settings in intellij. In the tab `Libraries` i clicked on the plus sign and copied the maven-repo-address into the corresponding field. Every address i added so far are already mentioned at the very end of my question. I am sorry if i did not understand you correctly. Java is giving me some trouble.

Answer (score -1):

This error may come even if you are not importing `org.apache.http.ssl.SSLContexts`

Try importing `httpcore` package from maven repository in pom.xml file.

Also check you have `httpclient` package.

*It's **not** required to have the same version for httpcore and httpclient*